# How to use jquery variable in php same page without submitted the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to pass a `Jquery` variable to a `php` variable  on the same page 
 when the list item changed

```
<select name="RegistrationTypeID"class="formselectbox"id="RD"
onchange="getText(this.val)">

<option value="">Select Registration Type</option>                                               
<option value="1">Contractor</option>
<option value="2">Exhibitor</option>
<option value="3">Media</option>
<option value="4">Organizer</option>
<option value="5">VIP</option>
<option value="6">Visitor</option>                                           
</select>

function getText(text){

var a = $("#RD option:selected").text();

  // i want variable  a to `php` variable a. on same page  
}
```

Comment: You can use AJAX to pass the variable to the server.

Comment: Also take care with the spaces in and around your attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by creating a http request to your php page like so:

```
var a = $("#RD option:selected").text();
$.get( "test.php", { variable: a } );
```

What you do here is send a request to the php file with a parameter named variable with the value of a.

In your php you need to store the data this you can do with [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: So we can use $_GET to get this variable as a php variable after using $.get( "test.php", { variable: a } );

Comment: my page URL is coded   so  we think we should use   $(location).attr('href');                      http://localhost/event_registration/admin/index.php?0/ftinjBXVUmq44H2kqy0ga0+8d1DsQpIy2LafARJXB6PAu3llnoGicc88XpEIp+mpULbIwBYatPLObN3/o69DWlpE1KnkxDBVwn0Vpu9mE=

Comment: You could use that or the plain js way `window.location.href`